# How can i change icon.png depending on app theme (day/night) android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable

I have a logo on my splash screen and two files:
**logo_night.png** and **logo_day.png**

How can i change this logo that will change depending on the theme of the app using these two files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is to use a `night` resource qualifier, so if you're using a dark theme it pulls the named resource from the equivalent `night` folder if it exists there.

You have three basic options with this I think:

- just call them both `logo.png`, but put one version in `drawable` and the other in `drawable-night`. That way, whenever you refer to `@drawable/logo` it'll pull the correct version depending on the theme. If you have multiple density versions, in `drawable-hdpi` etc, you'll need them in `drawable-night-hdpi` etc. (the qualifier order matters)
- if you're making your splash in the usual way, where you create a splash drawable with a background layer and your logo drawable on another layer, you could just make a `night` variant of this instead (in `drawable-night`). Each version can explicitly refer to `logo_day` or `logo_night` and you can just keep those PNGs in the normal `drawable` folder
- or you can make a `night` version of your splash theme, and explicitly set the background to the dark version of your splash drawable instead. Both your splash drawables can stay in the normal `drawable` folder

So basically, something's gotta get a version in a `night`-qualified resource folder, so it can provide an alternative resource for dark mode. It's up to you which resource in that hierarchy you want to make the night version of (or you can do it for all of them if you want).

Also bear in mind that your splash theme (if you're doing it that way) follows the *system's* dark mode setting. If you're implementing a toggle in your app, and you set it to dark mode, the splash will still show up as the light variant if that's what the device is set to. That theme is set before your app starts and gets to work out if it should be in dark or light mode

Comment: Yup, it really works perfectly for me when i created drawable-night, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using png format. You can call **.getTheme()** on context object to get current theme, make an if statement to decide which png to show.

For example in activity you can get theme by just calling `getTheme()` because ***this.getTheme()*** is implied.

Other possibility is to switch to vectors where you can define different colors for different themes they will change automatically when user changes theme. This is probably better and more scalable solution. You can find much more details [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html).